# pass to function: incremented integer inside array or set reset array with ternary operator or a custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ternary-operator

I have several arrays (in this example 8) holding information ("images adresses"):

```
var arr_1   = ["img1.jpg","img2.jpg","img3.jpg"];
var arr_2   = ["dis1.jpg","dis2.jpg","dis3.jpg","dis4.jpg","dis5.jpg","dis6.jpg"];
...
var arr_8   = ["rre.jpg","rre2.jpg","ree222.jpg","s4.jpg"];
```

Now I need to pass to different functions the value of each array, as I would need a Counter for each array I have made an integer array of size 8 defined as:

```
var indexes = new Array(8);
var counter = 0;
for (counter=0; counter<8; counter++){ 
    indexes[counter]=0;
}
```

so each entry will hold a number that will be a counter

```
indexes[0] represents the counter of array_1
indexes[1] represents the counter of array_2
...
indexes[7] represents the counter of array_8
```

so to pass the value to a function I am doing something like

```
myfunction("MyID"    , arr_1[indexes[0]++]);
myfunction("MyIDtr"  , arr_2[indexes[1]++]);
myfunction("MyIDfoo" , arr_3[indexes[2]++]);
...
myfunction("MyIDroot", arr_8[indexes[7]++]);
```

myfunction receives the id and a number representing a counter and tell corresponding array wich image adress it should take.

Now, How can I do something like

```
if(indexes[0] < arr_1.length){
     indexes[0]++
}else
     indexes[0] = 0;
```

inside the call of my function?

```
myfunction("MyID"    ,  logic   );
```

Is it neccesary to create a function or could it be done using ternary operator? If so how would look like the ternary expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that I completely understand your question, but maybe that helps you

```
myfunction("MyID"    , arr_1[(indexes[0]++)%arr_1.length]);
```

the % operator is Modulus (division remainder). It helps be sure that number will not be greater than arr_length you can check like that for example:

```
0%2 = 0
1%2 = 1
2%2 = 0
3%2 = 1
...
and so on
```

This is small useful trick for that cases

Comment: Sorry if I didnt make it clear,I want to pass every time my function is called a incremented integer holded in `indexes[0]` and then if value in that index is equal to the length of `array_1`, then reset value in `indexes[0]` so I can keep iterating...

Comment: why is it %, will that check the condition when is equal to arr_1.length, could you please explaint it in more detail?

Comment: Alright, I never used that modulus operator like that before but that is a great trick, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing `index[i]` as an argument, pass `i` :

```
myfunction("MyID",    arr_1, 0);
myfunction("MyIDtr",  arr_2, 1);
myfunction("MyIDfoo", arr_3, 2);
myfunction("MyIDbar", arr_4, 3);
```

Inside your function, access the `index` array :

```
function myfunction(id, arr, i){
   index[i] = (index[i]+1)%arr.length;
   arr[ index[i] ];
}
```

A cleaner variant would be to pack the array and its index together in an object :

```
var images_1 = {
    urls: arr_1,
    index: 0
},
images_2 = {
    urls: arr_2,
    index: 0
}, ...
```

Write your function so that it takes an `images` argument :

```
function myfunction(id, images){
    images.index = (images.index + 1) % images.urls.length;

    images.urls[images.index] ...
}
```

Last and not least, if you really have 8 arrays, and `_1`, `_2`, `_3` ... really are indexes, don't use separate variables : make an array (or a mapping) :

```
var images = [];
//you can use integers as keys
images[0] = { urls: [...], index: 0 };
images[1] = { urls: [...], index: 0 };

//or names which have some other meaning in your code
images["MyID"]    = { ... }
images["MyIDtr"]  = { ... }
images["MyIDfoo"] = { ... }
```

It will be easier loop through your structure, access your structure (`images[this.id]`) and shorten/extend it if the need arises.

Answer (score 1):

You can create iterator objects for each of your arrays and let those objects handle advancing of the index pointer:

```
function InfiniteArrayIterator(arr)
{
  this.arr = arr;
  this.i = 0;
}

InfiniteArrayIterator.prototype.getNext = function()
{
  var current = this.arr[this.i];

  // advance pointer    
  this.i = (this.i + 1) % this.arr.length;

  // and return current element      
  return current;
};

// your array definitions
var arr_1   = ["img1.jpg","img2.jpg","img3.jpg"];
var arr_2   = ["dis1.jpg","dis2.jpg","dis3.jpg","dis4.jpg","dis5.jpg"];

// define an iterator for each
var iterators = [
  new InfiniteArrayIterator(arr_1),
  new InfiniteArrayIterator(arr_2)
];
```

Then you simply pass this into your function:

```
myfunction("MyID"    , iterators[0].getNext());
myfunction("MyIDtr"  , iterators[1].getNext());
// etc.
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/atagoy/1/)

You can even initialize your arrays as this:

```
var arr_1 = new InfiniteArrayIterator(["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg"]);
```

And then:

```
myfunction("MyID"    , arr_1.getNext());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operators

Eg.

`indexes[0] = (indexes[0]<arr_1.length)?indexes[0]+1:0;`

Comment: So I would call `myfunction("MyID", indexes[0]<arr_1.length)?indexes[0]+1:0  ); `  ?

Comment: I think @Elephant placed a better answer

Comment: Please check the modulus operator (%) on google on the operation of it.